# Send an derived class object from one process to another via udp socket in c++

Tags: c++, vtable

Let's say that  we have a class, is called Derived that inherits from a class is called Base.  The  two classes contains only data that are in continuous memory regions. Is it possible to send an object of the derived class over network without implement any special function for serialize and de-serialize the member of the object? What will be happen with the vtable? The vtable keeps real address of the derived functions or just offset?

Have a look in the following piece of code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    char dummy[100];
    int c;
    ~Derived()
    {
    }
    void serialize(RtpComMsg_t msg)
    {
        msg.length = sizeof(*this);
        msg.data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(this);
        std::cout << "1.msg length" << msg.length << std::endl;
    }
};

void Base::serialize(RtpComMsg_t msg)
{
    msg.length = sizeof(*this);
    msg.data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(this);
    std::cout << "msg length" << msg.length << std::endl;
}



   //receive from network
void deserialize(void * data)
{
    Derived *d = reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(data);
}



int main()
{
     Base *b = new Derived()  ;
    b->a = 5;
    memcpy(((Derived*)b), "0xABCDEF", sizeof("0xABCDEF"));
    ((Derived*)b)->c = 10;
    RtpComMsg_t msg{};
    b->serialize(msg);
    unsigned char temp[sizeof(Derived)];
    memcpy(temp, b, sizeof(Derived));
    //send temp to network
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how would your 'receiver' reconstruct the object from a binary stream?

Comment: This will end in tears. Just use a proper serialization layer.

Comment: Would you just allocate "sizeof(Derived)" bytes and then copy the stream buffer to that?

Comment: Yes. The other side knows the size of the Derived class. The two process have access in a common interface that implements the Derived class

Comment: [Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library from boost may come in handy for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should never send a pointer via networking. Different OS, different hardware, different compiler, different compiler version, or even different program build - might potentially break the code. I don't even mention the possibility of received data having errors.

Best advise: make simple conventions - what kind of data it is and who is it for. In basic programs you can even simplify it (till your TCP socket fails to receive sent data for unknown reason, happened to me).

Comment: Yes this is correct. But we talk for the same environment that the processes run. In  this case is this safe?

Comment: I don't think it is safe, I think this may open the door into remote code execution attacks. Imagine one hijacked this connection, and sent code, and a pointer to it. This code would be easily executed by your program and this would literally do anything he wants.

Comment: @getsoubl if you receive data in the same process, then yes. If you communicate on the same system between different processes, then depends on implementation. It might work, it might not. You should never write code that depends too much on implementation. I can understand code that builds only on Linux or Windows 10, but not more specific than that. As mentioned, such code will be extremely unsafe for UB and security reasons.